# Python Selenium StaleElementReferenceException Finding Element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

So I have been using selenium to open a webpage and wait for a specific element to be loaded. Once that's loaded, I'm finding an element within the first element that's already loaded and getting a value from that element. But, every time I run the code I get a StaleElementReferenceException on the line that says price = float(...). This is weird to me because it didn't crash on the line before which has the same xpath search. I'm very new to this, any help would be appreciated!

```
browser.get(url + page)
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchResultsTable")))

price_element = element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult']")
price = float(price_element.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@style='color:white']").text[:1])
```

Comment: [what is staleelementreferenceexception](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp), and [how to deal with it](http://engineeringquality.blogspot.com/2013/08/ways-of-dealing-with.html)

Comment: I tried making every element with lambda so that nothing would be stale. But, now I get the problem where it's not waiting long enough, and the data I'm getting is incorrect. When I wait for the presence_of_element_located does it make sure that all sub-elements are loaded as well? Because I think those aren't getting loaded.